# Installing CentOS 6 - Device may need to be reinitialized

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos

I'm trying to install linux centOS 6 on my pc (on sun virtual machine - virtualbox). I'm installing on a empty partition of my hard drive. and my primary OS is windows 7 ultimate 64bit.

What should I do with this error?

Installing CentOS 6 - Device may need to be reinitialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use re-initialize ..... no need to worry
It will work for sure.
since it is new partition of your drive so reinitialisation will be done by your guest OS 
and the new filesystem will be created for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a new virtual disk when you create the VM, it should be ok to click re-initialize.